# WhenEvent and Piecewise inside NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise, event-detection

```
A = Table[Sin[2 Pi/ x], {x, 1, 50}];

NDSolve[{y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] ==
Piecewise[{{Interpolation[A, kkk[x]], z[x] == 1}, {0, True}}],
y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, kkk[0] == 100, z[0] == 0, 
WhenEvent[x > 9, {z[x] -> 1, kkk[x] -> 1}]}, y, {x, 0, 30},
 DiscreteVariables -> {kkk, z}]
```

By using above code I get this error

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {100.} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

but when I change the `WhenEvent` as follow there is no error.

```
WhenEvent[x > 9, {kkk[x] -> 1, z[x] -> 1}]}
```

Could anybody explain the reason behind this?
It is a simple example of what I am doing. I need to use Discrete Variables which change inside `WhenEvent` as a input of a function in `NDSolve`.

Comment: At `x=0`, `kkk[x]=100`, however your Interpolation only knows the value of A for x (different x...) up to 50 ,as you define in your Table. Hence, it must extrapolate.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli At x==0, kkk[0] is 100 but z[0] is also 0 so the first condition inside Piecewise is not satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This admittedly strange behavior does not occur at `x == 0`, as one might suppose, but at `x == 9`, as can be seen by using, for instance,

```
WhenEvent[x > 40, {z[x] -> 1, kkk[x] -> 1}]
```

for which no error message occurs.  For the code as in the question, at `x == 9`, first `z[x] -> 1` is executed, next `Piecewise` seems to be executed (because its argument has changed), creating an error message, and finally `kkk[x] -> 1` is executed.  In contrast,

```
WhenEvent[x > 9, {kkk[x] -> 1, z[x] -> 1}]
```

executes `kkk[x] -> 1` first at `x == 9`, so no error occurs, consistent with the behavior described in the question.  A somewhat similar situation is illustrated in the final example under "Possible Issues" in the `WhenEvent` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).  A robust solution is to execute both simultaneously,

```
WhenEvent[x > 9, {z[x], kkk[x]} -> {1, 1}]
```

which works well.